# how to upload file and get it content in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, node-modules

I am trying to upload xsls file and try to convert its content in JSON and show in console.
I am using this plugin to upload my file
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload
I make a simple demo of this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-payne-p7chg

I when used my service using this `sample file` https://gofile.io/?c=2wBegC
it shows me `binary` not JSON or content

```
app.use(upload()); // configure middleware
app.get("/abc", function(req, res) {
  res.send({ test: "sss" });
});
app.post("/upload", function(req, res) {
  console.log("ssss");
  console.log(req.files);

});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log("Express server listening on port ", PORT); // eslint-disable-line
});
```

I think i need to convert `binary` to some json object

[image]

Comment: Also, an XLSX file **is** binary data (it's a zip file with specific contents). I've no idea why you would think it would show you JSON or why you think it isn't showing you content.

Comment: yes I think i know convert `binary` to json

Comment: is there any way to read file content without saving the file ?in other words i don't want to save that file in any location .

Comment: What does "read file content" even mean to you? Are you wanting the raw bytes of the file so you can write a zip file decoder from scratch, and then an Excel parser for all the data inside it? That would be a massive amount of work. Have you considered looking for a library which someone has already written? Maybe you'll find one that expects to be passed a Buffer object in the first place.

Comment: if you download this file https://gofile.io/?c=2wBegC

Comment: Yes, it's an Excel file. That's rather my point.

Comment: you will see two rows .so that expected output is `[{sno:1,Name:'hello'},{sno:2,Name:'hello Test'}]`

Comment: so will I save file on server first then read the file contend from that location  ??

Comment: At no point did I say anything about having to save the file. Just that if you want a JavaScript representation of the data in the Excel file then you will need to parse the Excel file. It's Excel. Not JSON. (If it was JSON, you'd still need to parse it, it would just be a lot simpler to do as Node has native support for JSON parsing)

Comment: @Quentin can you do some changes on codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

try using the express-fileupload npm package that really helps all you need is this middleware

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload({
    createParentPath: true
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try excel2Json:

`npm install excel2Json --save`

Then:

````
const excel2Json = require('excel2json');

excel2Json('sample.xls', (err, output) => {
   // do stuff with your outputJSON
});

// Or with additional options
excel2Json('../test/sample.xls', {
    'convert_all_sheet': false,
    'return_type': 'File',
    'sheetName': 'survey'
}, (err, output) => {
 // do stuff with your outputJSON
});```
````

Comment: but i don't have have `excel` file.only `buffer`

Comment: @user944513 I'm not exactly sure what you want to accomplish then, but maybe this is what you're looking for? https://ciphertrick.com/read-excel-files-convert-json-node-js/